# window.onload triggered before font-face load

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, font-face

The following webpage loads Font Awesome, displays the icon `fa-check`, and has a `debugger` breakpoint on `window.onload`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        debugger;
      };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='fa fa-check fa-4x'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On Chrome (with the console open), the breakpoint is hit *after* the icon is rendered. This is the expected behaviour.

On Safari (with the console open), the breakpoint is hit *before* the icon is rendered. I am assuming this is a Safari bug.

How can I guarantee that `window.onload` triggers after the icon is rendered on Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring out exactly when a font has loaded on the page is unfortunately a very difficult problem, especially when you have to support multiple browsers/devices. Last time I took a survey there was no magic bullet but many people have written up their approaches. See [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/) and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/improve-page-performance-font-loader/) and [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-avoid-fout-by-adding-a-web-font-preloader--webdesign-8287).

Comment: I'm actually *only* interested in Safari, since I'm developing an iOS app with a `UIWebView` in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the font loading status using [`document.fonts.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts) which returns a promise you can resolve, using `then(...)`:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
  // Any operation that needs to be done only after all the fonts
  // have finished loading can go here.
});
```

See supported browsers here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts